# Function inside href returns false

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to have it where when clicked `sentajax` function is run and the variable is defined.

I have tried `onclick` already but then it conflicts with another JavaScript function that uses the id `link2` to change the color of the links when clicked.

It works perfectly on chrome but firefox treats the JavaScript as a url and tries to open a page

The code goes like this:

```
<a style="color:#000" id="link2"  href="javascript: var filelink='stitle.php';sentAjax('stitle.php');" > Title
```

Comment: Does `sentAjax` return anything? If yes, prefix it by `void`, eg `void sentAjax(..)`.

Comment: You should not execute JavaScript like this. Bind a proper event handler and prevent the default action, which is following the link.

Comment: @RobW yes sentAjax returns search results

Answer (score 1):

You can chain your code using addEventListener.

```
var link = document.getElementById ("link2");
link.addEventListener (myFnToChangeColor, false);
link.addEventListener (myAjaxFn, false);
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion I ll try this later didnt know about it

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely use event handlers instead. However, if you wish to use `href`, try the following:

```
href="javascript:var filelink='stitle.php';void sentAjax('stitle.php')"
```

Comment: Only the last `void` is necessary. `void` is used to return no value. In fact, prefixing a `javascript:...` bookmarklet by `;void 0` will also do the job.